# looking for SQLite structure for query with multiple selects

Tags: sqlite

I want to count by week number or weeks back number from today,  the percentage of retained customers.  list output would be weeknbr-year and a percentage corresponding to % customers that reordered since their first order.

customer_tbl has "account_creation" and "last_ordr_date")
the calculation from today's perspective is
count of custs that reordered before today and their first order, divided by
count of custs that first ordered between 21 and 14 days ago  , times 100

this first part is tricky for me as there need to be two 'where' clauses that are somehow joined to produce the single adoption rate value of retained custs / new custs.

Then, this needs to be adapted to produce a daily list report where each day exposes the average total of the daily reordered custs calc / the daily new custs calc

If someone can provide guidance.   This is for my restaurant where I am targeting new customer promotions and want to assess the effect - if that makes sense.

here is my starting code that produces new and retained customers for today

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS "newcustcount"
  FROM
  "customers_tbl"
WHERE
  DATE ("customers_tbl"."account_creation") BETWEEN DATE('now','localtime','-21 days') AND DATE('now','localtime','-14 days')

UNION

SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS "retainedcustcount"
  FROM
  "customers_tbl"
WHERE
  DATE ("customers_tbl"."account_creation") BETWEEN DATE('now','localtime','-21 days') AND DATE('now','localtime','-14 days')
  AND DATE("customers_tbl"."last_ordr_date") > DATE ("customers_tbl"."account_creation")
```

**  here is sample customer table  **
some rows have last ordr date after account creation date.  the count of these in the year-month time bracket = the numerator.    the total count of account creations in time bracket is the denominator.

```
customer_id account_creation    last_ordr_date
201394  12/27/2023  12/27/2023
201365  12/26/2023  12/26/2023
201366  12/26/2023  12/26/2023
201375  12/26/2023  12/26/2023
201315  12/23/2023  12/23/2023
201333  12/23/2023  12/23/2023
201254  12/22/2023  12/22/2023
201281  12/22/2023  12/22/2023
201294  12/22/2023  12/22/2023
201227  12/21/2023  12/21/2023
201243  12/21/2023  12/21/2023
201142  12/19/2023  12/19/2023
201137  12/18/2023  12/18/2023
201110  12/17/2023  12/17/2023
201113  12/17/2023  12/17/2023
201065  12/16/2023  12/16/2023
201072  12/16/2023  12/16/2023
201083  12/16/2023  12/16/2023
200956  12/14/2023  12/14/2023
200966  12/14/2023  12/14/2023
200972  12/14/2023  12/14/2023
200899  12/12/2023  12/12/2023
200876  12/11/2023  12/11/2023
173844  12/10/2023  3/5/2022
200823  12/10/2023  12/10/2023
200828  12/10/2023  12/10/2023
200769  12/9/2023   12/9/2023
200771  12/9/2023   12/9/2023
200790  12/9/2023   12/9/2023
200743  12/8/2023   12/8/2023
200747  12/8/2023   12/8/2023
200763  12/8/2023   12/8/2023
200701  12/7/2023   12/7/2023
200704  12/7/2023   12/7/2023
200715  12/7/2023   12/7/2023
201166  12/7/2023   12/19/2023
201369  12/7/2023   12/26/2023
200669  12/6/2023   12/6/2023
200564  12/3/2023   12/3/2023
200586  12/3/2023   12/3/2023
200587  12/3/2023   12/3/2023
200594  12/3/2023   12/3/2023
200596  12/3/2023   12/3/2023
200528  12/2/2023   12/2/2023
200531  12/2/2023   12/2/2023
174095  12/1/2023   3/11/2022
181400  12/1/2023   8/21/2022
185382  12/1/2023   11/20/2022
200468  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200483  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200486  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200502  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200505  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200510  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200511  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200513  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200514  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200518  12/1/2023   12/1/2023
200994  12/1/2023   12/15/2023
200432  11/30/2023  11/30/2023
200443  11/30/2023  11/30/2023
200449  11/30/2023  11/30/2023
200454  11/30/2023  11/30/2023
200456  11/30/2023  11/30/2023
200416  11/29/2023  11/29/2023
200427  11/29/2023  11/29/2023
175792  11/28/2023  4/19/2022
200381  11/28/2023  11/28/2023
200383  11/28/2023  11/28/2023
200305  11/26/2023  11/26/2023
200306  11/26/2023  11/26/2023
200312  11/26/2023  11/26/2023
200326  11/26/2023  11/26/2023
200333  11/26/2023  11/26/2023
200334  11/26/2023  11/26/2023
201168  11/26/2023  12/19/2023
200274  11/25/2023  11/25/2023
200293  11/25/2023  11/25/2023
200235  11/24/2023  11/24/2023
200237  11/24/2023  11/24/2023
200244  11/24/2023  11/24/2023
200256  11/24/2023  11/24/2023
186216  11/22/2023  12/14/2022
200220  11/22/2023  11/22/2023
200132  11/21/2023  11/21/2023
200162  11/21/2023  11/21/2023
200110  11/20/2023  11/20/2023
200120  11/20/2023  11/20/2023
200125  11/20/2023  11/20/2023
200069  11/19/2023  11/19/2023
200093  11/19/2023  11/19/2023
200024  11/18/2023  11/18/2023
200025  11/18/2023  11/18/2023
200064  11/18/2023  11/18/2023
200066  11/18/2023  11/18/2023
199958  11/17/2023  11/17/2023
199962  11/17/2023  11/17/2023
199931  11/16/2023  11/16/2023
199934  11/16/2023  11/16/2023
199937  11/16/2023  11/16/2023
199942  11/16/2023  11/16/2023
199903  11/15/2023  11/15/2023
199915  11/15/2023  11/15/2023
165663  11/14/2023  9/6/2021
199847  11/14/2023  11/14/2023
199871  11/14/2023  11/14/2023
199877  11/14/2023  11/14/2023
199880  11/14/2023  11/14/2023
199786  11/12/2023  11/12/2023
199802  11/12/2023  11/12/2023
199816  11/12/2023  11/12/2023
199822  11/12/2023  11/12/2023
200904  11/12/2023  12/12/2023
199776  11/11/2023  11/11/2023
199699  11/10/2023  11/10/2023
199706  11/10/2023  11/10/2023
199709  11/10/2023  11/10/2023
199719  11/10/2023  11/10/2023
199727  11/10/2023  11/10/2023
200320  11/10/2023  11/26/2023
201070  11/10/2023  12/16/2023
199643  11/9/2023   11/9/2023
199646  11/9/2023   11/9/2023
199648  11/9/2023   11/9/2023
199612  11/8/2023   11/8/2023
199536  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199557  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199558  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199560  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199561  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199563  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199565  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199569  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199570  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199572  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
199583  11/7/2023   11/7/2023
200379  11/7/2023   11/28/2023
200788  11/7/2023   12/9/2023
199487  11/5/2023   11/5/2023
199499  11/5/2023   11/5/2023
199513  11/5/2023   11/5/2023
199712  11/5/2023   11/10/2023
199982  11/5/2023   11/17/2023
200496  11/5/2023   12/1/2023
200760  11/5/2023   12/8/2023
201034  11/5/2023   12/15/2023
199434  11/4/2023   11/4/2023
199460  11/4/2023   11/4/2023
199462  11/4/2023   11/4/2023
199371  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
199378  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
199384  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
199395  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
199410  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
199417  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
199422  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
199424  11/3/2023   11/3/2023
186768  10/31/2023  12/29/2022
199231  10/31/2023  10/31/2023
199253  10/31/2023  10/31/2023
199263  10/31/2023  10/31/2023
199264  10/31/2023  10/31/2023
199265  10/31/2023  10/31/2023
199289  10/31/2023  10/31/2023
199291  10/31/2023  10/31/2023
199595  10/31/2023  11/8/2023
200130  10/31/2023  11/21/2023
201163  10/31/2023  12/19/2023
184514  10/30/2023  10/31/2022
199199  10/30/2023  10/30/2023
199200  10/30/2023  10/30/2023
201396  10/30/2023  12/27/2023
160865  10/29/2023  6/2/2021
165548  10/29/2023  9/4/2021
199139  10/29/2023  10/29/2023
199161  10/29/2023  10/29/2023
199177  10/29/2023  10/29/2023
199181  10/29/2023  10/29/2023
199188  10/29/2023  10/29/2023
199190  10/29/2023  10/29/2023
183309  10/28/2023  10/5/2022
199066  10/28/2023  10/28/2023
199068  10/28/2023  10/28/2023
199106  10/28/2023  10/28/2023
199122  10/28/2023  10/28/2023
199123  10/28/2023  10/28/2023
201236  10/28/2023  12/21/2023
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results from it would be useful.

Comment: (preferably as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that can just be copy and pasted into a sqlite3 session)

Comment: would this suffice Shawn?

Answer (score 0):

Use subselects:

```sql
SELECT 100 * CAST((
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS retainedcustcount
    FROM customers_tbl
    WHERE DATE (account_creation)
        BETWEEN DATE('now','localtime','-21 days')
        AND DATE('now','localtime','-14 days')
    AND DATE(last_ordr_date)
    > DATE (account_creation)
) AS FLOAT) / (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS newcustcount
    FROM customers_tbl
    WHERE DATE (account_creation)
        BETWEEN DATE('now','localtime','-21 days')
        AND DATE('now','localtime','-14 days')
)
```

Without the CAST, you'll only get integer division, i.e. 90% instead of 90.9090909%.

I randomly generated 1000 customers, the ones involved in the query were

```
1 2023-12-13 2023-12-21
2 2023-12-06 2023-12-17
3 2023-12-13 2023-12-15
4 2023-12-06 2023-12-24
5 2023-12-12 2023-12-18
6 2023-12-13 2023-12-15
7 2023-12-12 2023-12-13
8 2023-12-08 2023-12-08
9 2023-12-12 2023-12-14
10 2023-12-09 2023-12-24
11 2023-12-12 2023-12-17
```

You can see that #8 didn't reorder, so we have 10 / 11 = 90.90909090909090909090.

Comment: really appreciate your refinement of a single target date (today) result.   Apologies I'm somewhat a tinkerer but have a valid business need for this.    How would you extend this code to produce a list report over say 12 prior months?  (I posted actual customer data spanning 1 month, if useful)

Comment: @Regis: Can you give an example using the data you posted?

Comment: Hi,  thanks for looking in.  The 90% result that was generated with the nested selects code above looks like what I want when calculated for today (target date).   what i need in the final presentation is something I can chart over time, showing customer adoption rate.  Therefore the nested substring code above needs to be rerun for each target date going back a year, producing a two column list report.

Comment: That's why it's not wise to ask two questions in one. You only get half an answer, and the person answering gets no points.

Comment: My etiquette incompetence.    How can I close this request to properly credit you for initial code response?